# Upgrading Rails from 4.2 to 5.2, implementing throw(:abort) in callbacks is raising a Mongoid validation exception, how to prevent that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, upgrade

The upgrade I'm working on is

- Ruby 2.6
- MongoDB 3.6
- Mongoid from 5.0 to 7.1
- Rails from 4.2 to 5.2

I have a call back that halts future callbacks under a condition. Now that I have to use `throw(:abort)` to halt callbacks and prevent a `save` operation Mongoid will then throw:

```
Mongoid::Errors::Callback:

       message:
         Calling save! on Survey resulted in a false return from a callback.
       summary:
         If a before callback returns false when using Document.create!, Document#save!, or Document#update_attributes! this error will get raised since the document did not actually get saved.
       resolution:
         Double check all before callbacks to make sure they are not unintentionally returning false.
```

This is problematic. We're not even expecting an error message, that is logged and we move on. We just want `record.save` to return `false`. How do I suppress this exception from Mongoid?

Comment: your code was working, and when you upgrade it breaks. It's not a good idea to suppress the error, you should find out why it happens and fix the root cause.

Comment: Thanks Les, I think you misunderstand my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was throwing as well as returning false. Just throw(:abort).